# Yii, joining 2 dropdown lists into 1

Tags: list, yii

So basically I have 2 different drop down lists, for example, A has 10 options and B has 10 options.

How can I have them both in 1 single drop down? For example, the top 10 options from A and the bottom 10 from B?

The below is the drop down A:

```
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
    <?php $client = Client::model()->findByPk(1);?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'clientPackagedService_id', CHtml::listData($client->clientPackagedservices(array('condition'=>'client_id='.$client->id.' AND booking_id IS NULL')),'id','packagedServiceInfo'),
        array('disabled'=>'disabled', 'prompt'=>'Select Packaged Service...')               
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
```

The below is the drop down B:

```
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'service_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'service_id',  GxHtml::listDataEx(Service::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
        //array( 'prompt'=>'Select Service...')
        array( //   
                    //'disabled'=>$disabledValue, //    
                    'enabled'=>true, 
                    'prompt' => 'Select service...',
                    'ajax' => array( 'type'=>'POST', //request type 
                        'url'=>CController::createUrl('updateMasseuseAndStationListSID'), //url to call.
                        'data'=>array('service_id'=>'js:this.value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
                        'dataType'=>'json', 
                        'success'=>'js:function(data) {
                            //alert(data.masseuse);
                            var mass="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'masseuse_id').'"; 
                            $(mass).html(data.masseuse); 
                            $(mass).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                            $(mass+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                            $(mass+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px");                              

                            var station="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'station_id').'"; 
                            $(station).html(data.station); 
                            $(station).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                            $(station+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                            $(station+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px"); 

                            //alert(data.timeEnd);
                            var timeEnd="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'timeEnd').'";
                            $(timeEnd).val(data.timeEnd);                           

                        }',                         
                    ) 
    )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'service_id'); ?>
```

How can I join them both and then remain the same operation of Ajax?

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine result of clientPackagedservices() with Service::model()->findAllAttributes() inside your controller and then pass it to the view file

Comment: Do you happen to have an example that I can have reference of? I know what you're saying, just that I've never done it.